# selenium find_element_by_xpath returns NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, selenium

I'm working with selenium but im having problems with the `find_element_by_xpath` method.
Having this tag from the https://citizenportal.rld.state.nm.us/default.aspx website:

```
<a title="Permits" href="javascript:void(0);" module="Permits">Permits</a>
```

Im trying to create a click event to click on the permits tag by doing:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://citizenportal.rld.state.nm.us/default.aspx')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="Permits"]').click()
```

However im getting this error and i cant figure it out

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-ecbedf623e4f> in <module>()
      6 driver.get('https://citizenportal.rld.state.nm.us/default.aspx')
      7 
----> 8 driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="Permits"]').click()
      9 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.pyc in find_element_by_xpath(self, xpath)
    304             driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/td[1]')
    305         """
--> 306         return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
    307 
    308     def find_elements_by_xpath(self, xpath):

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.pyc in find_element(self, by, value)
    782         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
    783             'using': by,
--> 784             'value': value})['value']
    785 
    786     def find_elements(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.pyc in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    247         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    248         if response:
--> 249             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    250             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    251                 response.get('value', None))

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.pyc in check_response(self, response)
    191         elif exception_class == UnexpectedAlertPresentException and 'alert' in value:
    192             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, value['alert'].get('text'))
--> 193         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    194 
    195     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@title="Permits"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
```

I've tried different combinations but it keeps returning an error. What am i doing wrong?

EDIT that includes the hole span and its elements.

```
<span style="display:inline-block;" id="span_tab_1">                       
    <table role="presentation" tag="navbar" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tab_bar_table ACA_Nowrap">                           
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="ACA_ItemLeft ACA_LeftOff"></td>                                  
                <div>                                           
                    <a title="Permits" href="javascript:void(0);" module="Permits">Permits</a>                                       
                </div>
                <td class="ACA_ItemCenter ACA_ItemCenter_FontSize ACA_CenterOff">   
                </td>                                   
                <td class="ACA_ItemRight ACA_RightOff"></td>                           
        </tr>                       
 <      /tbody>
    </table>                    
 </span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath is fine. I prefer to use CSS selectors, e.g. `"a[title='Permit']"`, since they are faster and better supported.

The problem is that the element you want is inside an IFRAME.

```
<iframe id="ACAFrame" name="ACAFrame" ... src="/Welcome.aspx">
```

You will need to switch into that frame and then your find will work.

See [this page](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Anchor tags do not have a standard title attribute: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

I suggest using:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Permits').click()
```

per: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text

Comment: Is there a way to get the title reference?. Seems that there are other "permits" reference in the body of the website

Comment: As far as I can tell from their documentation, no. Are the other instances of "Permits" in the context of anchor tags?

Comment: Yeah it's going to another site and not the one i need to get to. I included the whole span section to provide more context.  I tried to to a click event using the id =span_tab_1 but that also returned an error

Comment: You could get an attribute by tagname, but this only returns the first one in the DOM, so selenium-python does not support what you are trying to do in this case. There is a Java implementation that supports getting many elements by tag name, where you could loop over those and check the title attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you try searching for the elements within the iframe you must have to **switch the focus to the iframe** that you are dealing with.

Do this before searching for the elements within the iframe:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("iframeTitle")));
```

In this case, the iframe Title is : **ACAFrame**

below is the updated code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://citizenportal.rld.state.nm.us/default.aspx')
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name('ACAFrame')));
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="Permits"]').click()
```